# Obtener días entre dos fechas basadas en 1 año de 360 días PHP

Tags: php, php7, php5

Hola necesito sacar a partir de 2 fecha cuantos días ha transcurrido basado en meses de 30 días que a 1 año es 360 días, sin calcular los años bisiestos.

Este es mi código actual, pero el resultado arrojado es en base a 365 días que tiene el año:

```
        $fecha_entrada = "2014-08-04";
        $fechaActual = "2020-02-13";
        $date1 = new DateTime("$fechaActual");
        $date2 = new DateTime("$fecha_entrada");
        $diff = $date1->diff($date2);


        $fechaFinal = $diff->days;
        echo $fechaFinal; // El resultado es de 2019 días
```

Realizando la cuenta a 1 año de 30 días el mes el resultado debería ser de 1990 días.

¿Cómo puedo hacer eso?

Gracias.

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Quieres hacer cálculos en base a algo imaginario que consistiría en creer que todos los meses del año tienen 30 días? Pon algunos ejemplos de lo que esperas obtener para ver si entendemos. Por ejemplo, en tu ensoñación de calendario febrero tendría 30 días? Pon un ejemplo que incluya a febrero.

Comment: Sí exactamente, en contabilidad las cuentas se hacen basadas en 30 días, o sea que cada mes para ellos tienen 30 días. En Excel lo hacen con una función llamada DIAS360 con una formula como esta: =DIAS360(C4;D4)+1

Answer (score 1):

Imderf,
Yo creio que el resultado seria 1994 dias.
Haciendo como tu has dicho, la cuenta seria así.

```
1 - Obtner los dias transcurridos  = 2019 días
2 - Obtener el intero de los años (2019 / 365) = 5,531507
3 - Obtener los dias para disminuir (5 * 5) = 25
4 - Obtener los dias com año de 360 dias (2019 - 25) = 1994 días
```

Saludos
Bonfim